# tcl failed to load package when remote desktop with root account

Tags: tcl, ubuntu-12.04, package, remote-desktop

The OS is Ubuntu 12.04.

I have the tcl scripts to do some job, which require some package, as:

```
package require ParseConfig
```

If I run the scripts in this Ubuntu directly with root account, then the scripts could run well.

However, if I access the Ubuntu by remote desktop(by installing `vncserver`), then it will report:

```
Can't find package ParseConfig while executing "package require ParseConfig".
```

The account for the remote access is root too.

Comment: Can you run `puts $auto_path` in both cases and edit your question with results?

Comment: Could well be differences in environment; that often varies when you log in in different ways or log into different systems.